# Algorithm to convert RGB to HSV and HSV to RGB in range 0-255 for both

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I am looking for color space converter from RGB to HSV, specifically for the range 0 to 255 for both color spaces.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

I've used these for a long time - no idea where they came from at this point... Note that the inputs and outputs, except for the angle in degrees, are in the range of 0 to 1.0.

NOTE: this code does no real sanity checking on inputs. Proceed with caution!

```
typedef struct {
    double r;       // a fraction between 0 and 1
    double g;       // a fraction between 0 and 1
    double b;       // a fraction between 0 and 1
} rgb;

typedef struct {
    double h;       // angle in degrees
    double s;       // a fraction between 0 and 1
    double v;       // a fraction between 0 and 1
} hsv;

static hsv   rgb2hsv(rgb in);
static rgb   hsv2rgb(hsv in);

hsv rgb2hsv(rgb in)
{
    hsv         out;
    double      min, max, delta;

    min = in.r < in.g ? in.r : in.g;
    min = min  < in.b ? min  : in.b;

    max = in.r > in.g ? in.r : in.g;
    max = max  > in.b ? max  : in.b;

    out.v = max;                                // v
    delta = max - min;
    if (delta < 0.00001)
    {
        out.s = 0;
        out.h = 0; // undefined, maybe nan?
        return out;
    }
    if( max > 0.0 ) { // NOTE: if Max is == 0, this divide would cause a crash
        out.s = (delta / max);                  // s
    } else {
        // if max is 0, then r = g = b = 0              
        // s = 0, h is undefined
        out.s = 0.0;
        out.h = NAN;                            // its now undefined
        return out;
    }
    if( in.r >= max )                           // > is bogus, just keeps compilor happy
        out.h = ( in.g - in.b ) / delta;        // between yellow & magenta
    else
    if( in.g >= max )
        out.h = 2.0 + ( in.b - in.r ) / delta;  // between cyan & yellow
    else
        out.h = 4.0 + ( in.r - in.g ) / delta;  // between magenta & cyan

    out.h *= 60.0;                              // degrees

    if( out.h < 0.0 )
        out.h += 360.0;

    return out;
}


rgb hsv2rgb(hsv in)
{
    double      hh, p, q, t, ff;
    long        i;
    rgb         out;

    if(in.s <= 0.0) {       // < is bogus, just shuts up warnings
        out.r = in.v;
        out.g = in.v;
        out.b = in.v;
        return out;
    }
    hh = in.h;
    if(hh >= 360.0) hh = 0.0;
    hh /= 60.0;
    i = (long)hh;
    ff = hh - i;
    p = in.v * (1.0 - in.s);
    q = in.v * (1.0 - (in.s * ff));
    t = in.v * (1.0 - (in.s * (1.0 - ff)));

    switch(i) {
    case 0:
        out.r = in.v;
        out.g = t;
        out.b = p;
        break;
    case 1:
        out.r = q;
        out.g = in.v;
        out.b = p;
        break;
    case 2:
        out.r = p;
        out.g = in.v;
        out.b = t;
        break;

    case 3:
        out.r = p;
        out.g = q;
        out.b = in.v;
        break;
    case 4:
        out.r = t;
        out.g = p;
        out.b = in.v;
        break;
    case 5:
    default:
        out.r = in.v;
        out.g = p;
        out.b = q;
        break;
    }
    return out;     
}
```

Comment: @Stargazer712 If you do the math,it should be ==, but if you use that you may get a complaint about comparing floats. While theoretically it's impossible for it to be >, using ">=" instead of "==" shuts down the compiler error that I get on the Mac using llvm/Xcode,

Comment: if(in.s <= 0.0) { 
        if(isnan(in.h)) {             out.r = in.v;
            out.g = in.v;
            out.b = in.v;
            return out;
        }
        // error - should never happen
        out.r = 0.0;
        out.g = 0.0;
        out.b = 0.0;
        return out;
    }

This part of code is gives wrong results. When you have white rgb color and convert it to hsv and then back to rgb the result becomes black. rgb (1.0, 1.0, 1.0) translates to hsv as (0.0, 0.0, 1.0) and hsv 0.0 0.0 1.0 translates to rgb as (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)

Comment: corrected version of the that part is

if(in.s <= 0.0) { 
          out.r = in.v;
            out.g = in.v;
            out.b = in.v;
            return out;
}

Comment: @user65721 thanks for catching and fixing this. I just updated the code.

Comment: Why is `60` used as an approximation for `180 / pi`? This would seem very inaccurate.

Comment: @Gerard out is in degrees. 60 is 1/6th of a full circle. This is not radians.

Comment: This rgb2hsv code lacks a check if you give it a grayscale. All three rgb components are equal, which results in a delta equal to zero. This produces a division by 0.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux Good catch! Suggested fix?

Comment: @DavidH: I edited it. Although I don't know the HSV model exactly. I think my edit is correct, but please verify.

Comment: The reason for the `>=` and compiler error is because `double == double` is invalid and illegal in most compilers. Floating point arithmetic and floating point storage means that two values can be equal in _approximate_ value, but not equal in stored value even though formulaically they are the same. You're supposed to do `abs(double_a - double_b) <= epsilon` where epsilon is some value, typically `1e-4`.

Comment: @JoachimBrandonLeBlanc well you could just make it > -0.0000001 or so - the problem is deciding what epsilon should be. As I recall, the number is actually 0.0, its just that the code cannot use '==' without warning.

Comment: For rgb2hsv, where in.r >= max, why isn't the code using the mod operator?  Shouldn't the out.h be calculated as 
"out.h = ((in.g - in.b) / delta) % 6;" ?

Comment: When I read "// percent" I think "value going from 0 to 100", not 0.0 to 1.0. Maybe it doesn't mean what it looks like in english, I don't know. But that's confusing ;)

Comment: @JoachimBrandonLeBlanc: _"double == double is invalid and illegal in most compilers"_ That is not true. Comparing two floating-point values for equality is *completely well-defined* and *a legal thing to do*. No mainstream and/or compliant compiler will prevent you from doing it. The problem is that you may not get the answer you actually wanted, and likely intended to perform a looser comparison.

Comment: No one said it’s illegal - just bad practice!

Comment: Actually someone did, to quote verbatim  **"is invalid and illegal in most compilers"**. And to use `<=` is still using `==`, better to simply stick with `<`. These are just nit-picks, the code above was very helpful. :)

Comment: in hsv2rgb, inside the `if (in.s<=0.0) {}` block, should each `in.v` not be `255-(in.v*255)` or similar?

Comment: @NickSlash as you can see, I posted this 10 years ago when I was using it. At this time I can’t answer your question. Try converting back and forth and see if you maintain the original values. Good luck!

Comment: @DavidH Is the reason you made your own converter rather than using the premade one in the Color class because yours is faster?

Comment: @SomeGuy I used this over 10 years ago for a Max app, don’t believe there was any system api to do it then.

Comment: @DavidH I think the rgb2hsv code can be simplified because when max is 0, delta is 0 too.

Comment: @OlivierSohn possibly but I’m reluctant to change this code as it’s been working flawlessly for years.

Answer (score 51):

You can also try this code without floats (faster but less accurate):

```
typedef struct RgbColor
{
    unsigned char r;
    unsigned char g;
    unsigned char b;
} RgbColor;

typedef struct HsvColor
{
    unsigned char h;
    unsigned char s;
    unsigned char v;
} HsvColor;

RgbColor HsvToRgb(HsvColor hsv)
{
    RgbColor rgb;
    unsigned char region, remainder, p, q, t;
    
    if (hsv.s == 0)
    {
        rgb.r = hsv.v;
        rgb.g = hsv.v;
        rgb.b = hsv.v;
        return rgb;
    }
    
    region = hsv.h / 43;
    remainder = (hsv.h - (region * 43)) * 6; 
    
    p = (hsv.v * (255 - hsv.s)) >> 8;
    q = (hsv.v * (255 - ((hsv.s * remainder) >> 8))) >> 8;
    t = (hsv.v * (255 - ((hsv.s * (255 - remainder)) >> 8))) >> 8;
    
    switch (region)
    {
        case 0:
            rgb.r = hsv.v; rgb.g = t; rgb.b = p;
            break;
        case 1:
            rgb.r = q; rgb.g = hsv.v; rgb.b = p;
            break;
        case 2:
            rgb.r = p; rgb.g = hsv.v; rgb.b = t;
            break;
        case 3:
            rgb.r = p; rgb.g = q; rgb.b = hsv.v;
            break;
        case 4:
            rgb.r = t; rgb.g = p; rgb.b = hsv.v;
            break;
        default:
            rgb.r = hsv.v; rgb.g = p; rgb.b = q;
            break;
    }
    
    return rgb;
}

HsvColor RgbToHsv(RgbColor rgb)
{
    HsvColor hsv;
    unsigned char rgbMin, rgbMax;

    rgbMin = rgb.r < rgb.g ? (rgb.r < rgb.b ? rgb.r : rgb.b) : (rgb.g < rgb.b ? rgb.g : rgb.b);
    rgbMax = rgb.r > rgb.g ? (rgb.r > rgb.b ? rgb.r : rgb.b) : (rgb.g > rgb.b ? rgb.g : rgb.b);
    
    hsv.v = rgbMax;
    if (hsv.v == 0)
    {
        hsv.h = 0;
        hsv.s = 0;
        return hsv;
    }

    hsv.s = 255 * long(rgbMax - rgbMin) / hsv.v;
    if (hsv.s == 0)
    {
        hsv.h = 0;
        return hsv;
    }

    if (rgbMax == rgb.r)
        hsv.h = 0 + 43 * (rgb.g - rgb.b) / (rgbMax - rgbMin);
    else if (rgbMax == rgb.g)
        hsv.h = 85 + 43 * (rgb.b - rgb.r) / (rgbMax - rgbMin);
    else
        hsv.h = 171 + 43 * (rgb.r - rgb.g) / (rgbMax - rgbMin);

    return hsv;
}
```

Note that this algorithm uses `0-255` as its range (not `0-360`) as that was requested by the author of this question.

Comment: You can convert all 16,777,216 possible RGB colors to HSV and back again to RGB. Unfortunately, using this algorithm you will find that some colors will not roundtrip well. Perhaps they perceptually look about the same but numerically there is a substantial difference, e.g. (0, 237, 11) will roundtrip to (0, 237, 0) etc. This is not the case when using David H's algorithm based on floating point calculations.

Comment: @rightaway717 - this gives me the full range, maybe you're using 0-360 as the range?  This algorithm (thankfully) uses 0x00 - 0xFF as it's range

Comment: @AnneQuinn correct! I expected it to be 0-360, but I just didn't have enough passion to figure out what was wrong, when I saw that the accepted answer just worked. I think Leszek should've mentioned hue range in the answer, though thank him for posting it anyways.

Answer (score 26):

I wrote this in HLSL for our rendering engine, it has no conditions in it:

```
    float3  HSV2RGB( float3 _HSV )
    {
        _HSV.x = fmod( 100.0 + _HSV.x, 1.0 );                                       // Ensure [0,1[

        float   HueSlice = 6.0 * _HSV.x;                                            // In [0,6[
        float   HueSliceInteger = floor( HueSlice );
        float   HueSliceInterpolant = HueSlice - HueSliceInteger;                   // In [0,1[ for each hue slice

        float3  TempRGB = float3(   _HSV.z * (1.0 - _HSV.y),
                                    _HSV.z * (1.0 - _HSV.y * HueSliceInterpolant),
                                    _HSV.z * (1.0 - _HSV.y * (1.0 - HueSliceInterpolant)) );

        // The idea here to avoid conditions is to notice that the conversion code can be rewritten:
        //    if      ( var_i == 0 ) { R = V         ; G = TempRGB.z ; B = TempRGB.x }
        //    else if ( var_i == 2 ) { R = TempRGB.x ; G = V         ; B = TempRGB.z }
        //    else if ( var_i == 4 ) { R = TempRGB.z ; G = TempRGB.x ; B = V     }
        // 
        //    else if ( var_i == 1 ) { R = TempRGB.y ; G = V         ; B = TempRGB.x }
        //    else if ( var_i == 3 ) { R = TempRGB.x ; G = TempRGB.y ; B = V     }
        //    else if ( var_i == 5 ) { R = V         ; G = TempRGB.x ; B = TempRGB.y }
        //
        // This shows several things:
        //  . A separation between even and odd slices
        //  . If slices (0,2,4) and (1,3,5) can be rewritten as basically being slices (0,1,2) then
        //      the operation simply amounts to performing a "rotate right" on the RGB components
        //  . The base value to rotate is either (V, B, R) for even slices or (G, V, R) for odd slices
        //
        float   IsOddSlice = fmod( HueSliceInteger, 2.0 );                          // 0 if even (slices 0, 2, 4), 1 if odd (slices 1, 3, 5)
        float   ThreeSliceSelector = 0.5 * (HueSliceInteger - IsOddSlice);          // (0, 1, 2) corresponding to slices (0, 2, 4) and (1, 3, 5)

        float3  ScrollingRGBForEvenSlices = float3( _HSV.z, TempRGB.zx );           // (V, Temp Blue, Temp Red) for even slices (0, 2, 4)
        float3  ScrollingRGBForOddSlices = float3( TempRGB.y, _HSV.z, TempRGB.x );  // (Temp Green, V, Temp Red) for odd slices (1, 3, 5)
        float3  ScrollingRGB = lerp( ScrollingRGBForEvenSlices, ScrollingRGBForOddSlices, IsOddSlice );

        float   IsNotFirstSlice = saturate( ThreeSliceSelector );                   // 1 if NOT the first slice (true for slices 1 and 2)
        float   IsNotSecondSlice = saturate( ThreeSliceSelector-1.0 );              // 1 if NOT the first or second slice (true only for slice 2)

        return  lerp( ScrollingRGB.xyz, lerp( ScrollingRGB.zxy, ScrollingRGB.yzx, IsNotSecondSlice ), IsNotFirstSlice );    // Make the RGB rotate right depending on final slice index
    }
```

Comment: Do you have the other way conversion (RGB2HSV)? using the same approach?

Answer (score 9):

Here's a C implementation based on Agoston's *[Computer Graphics and Geometric Modeling: Implementation and Algorithms](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b138805)* p. 304, with *H* ∈ [0, 360] and *S*,*V* ∈ [0, 1].

```c
#include <math.h>

typedef struct {
    double r;       // ∈ [0, 1]
    double g;       // ∈ [0, 1]
    double b;       // ∈ [0, 1]
} rgb;

typedef struct {
    double h;       // ∈ [0, 360]
    double s;       // ∈ [0, 1]
    double v;       // ∈ [0, 1]
} hsv;

rgb hsv2rgb(hsv HSV)
{
    rgb RGB;
    double H = HSV.h, S = HSV.s, V = HSV.v,
            P, Q, T,
            fract;

    (H == 360.)?(H = 0.):(H /= 60.);
    fract = H - floor(H);

    P = V*(1. - S);
    Q = V*(1. - S*fract);
    T = V*(1. - S*(1. - fract));

    if      (0. <= H && H < 1.)
        RGB = (rgb){.r = V, .g = T, .b = P};
    else if (1. <= H && H < 2.)
        RGB = (rgb){.r = Q, .g = V, .b = P};
    else if (2. <= H && H < 3.)
        RGB = (rgb){.r = P, .g = V, .b = T};
    else if (3. <= H && H < 4.)
        RGB = (rgb){.r = P, .g = Q, .b = V};
    else if (4. <= H && H < 5.)
        RGB = (rgb){.r = T, .g = P, .b = V};
    else if (5. <= H && H < 6.)
        RGB = (rgb){.r = V, .g = P, .b = Q};
    else
        RGB = (rgb){.r = 0., .g = 0., .b = 0.};

    return RGB;
}
```

Comment: Is there similar C code for the conversion from HSV to RGB? Thanks!

Comment: @user3236841 The pseudo-code for that is on the previous page (p. 303) of Agoston's [_Computer Graphics and Geometric Modeling: Implementation and Algorithms_](https://isidore.co/calibre/browse/book/5588).

Comment: Please check - this is HSL2RGB, not the HSV.

Answer (score 8):

this should be on here:
it works anyway. And it looks good compared to the above ones.

hlsl code

```
        float3 Hue(float H)
        {
            half R = abs(H * 6 - 3) - 1;
            half G = 2 - abs(H * 6 - 2);
            half B = 2 - abs(H * 6 - 4);
            return saturate(half3(R,G,B));
        }

        half4 HSVtoRGB(in half3 HSV)
        {
            return half4(((Hue(HSV.x) - 1) * HSV.y + 1) * HSV.z,1);
        }
```

float3 is 16 bit precision vector3 data type, i.e. float3 hue() is returns a data type (x,y,z) e.g. (r,g,b), half is same with half precision, 8bit, a float4 is (r,g,b,a) 4 values.

Comment: Needs some type definitions for `half`, `half4`, `half3`, `float3`, et cetera.

Comment: half4 is color(r,g,b,a) or any 4x half precision float, can be full precision too, its just a vector4

Comment: what is saturate() ?

Comment: saturate() is available in HLSL code reference: saturate(x) gives x clamped/clipped between 0 and 1 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-saturate

Comment: Could you explain the return statement in HSVtoRGB?  It appears to be the 3 element RGB vector returned by Hue multiplied by a scalar - resulting in something like [k*r, k*g, k*b, 1]

Comment: Sorry I didn't design the algorythm so i didn't run through the maths, I just copied it in some work and then posted it here.

Answer (score 7):

@fins's answer has an overflow issue on Arduio as you turn the saturation down. Here it is with some values converted to int to prevent that.

```
typedef struct RgbColor
{
    unsigned char r;
    unsigned char g;
    unsigned char b;
} RgbColor;

typedef struct HsvColor
{
    unsigned char h;
    unsigned char s;
    unsigned char v;
} HsvColor;

RgbColor HsvToRgb(HsvColor hsv)
{
    RgbColor rgb;
    unsigned char region, p, q, t;
    unsigned int h, s, v, remainder;

    if (hsv.s == 0)
    {
        rgb.r = hsv.v;
        rgb.g = hsv.v;
        rgb.b = hsv.v;
        return rgb;
    }

    // converting to 16 bit to prevent overflow
    h = hsv.h;
    s = hsv.s;
    v = hsv.v;

    region = h / 43;
    remainder = (h - (region * 43)) * 6; 

    p = (v * (255 - s)) >> 8;
    q = (v * (255 - ((s * remainder) >> 8))) >> 8;
    t = (v * (255 - ((s * (255 - remainder)) >> 8))) >> 8;

    switch (region)
    {
        case 0:
            rgb.r = v;
            rgb.g = t;
            rgb.b = p;
            break;
        case 1:
            rgb.r = q;
            rgb.g = v;
            rgb.b = p;
            break;
        case 2:
            rgb.r = p;
            rgb.g = v;
            rgb.b = t;
            break;
        case 3:
            rgb.r = p;
            rgb.g = q;
            rgb.b = v;
            break;
        case 4:
            rgb.r = t;
            rgb.g = p;
            rgb.b = v;
            break;
        default:
            rgb.r = v;
            rgb.g = p;
            rgb.b = q;
            break;
    }

    return rgb;
}

HsvColor RgbToHsv(RgbColor rgb)
{
    HsvColor hsv;
    unsigned char rgbMin, rgbMax;

    rgbMin = rgb.r < rgb.g ? (rgb.r < rgb.b ? rgb.r : rgb.b) : (rgb.g < rgb.b ? rgb.g : rgb.b);
    rgbMax = rgb.r > rgb.g ? (rgb.r > rgb.b ? rgb.r : rgb.b) : (rgb.g > rgb.b ? rgb.g : rgb.b);

    hsv.v = rgbMax;
    if (hsv.v == 0)
    {
        hsv.h = 0;
        hsv.s = 0;
        return hsv;
    }

    hsv.s = 255 * ((long)(rgbMax - rgbMin)) / hsv.v;
    if (hsv.s == 0)
    {
        hsv.h = 0;
        return hsv;
    }

    if (rgbMax == rgb.r)
        hsv.h = 0 + 43 * (rgb.g - rgb.b) / (rgbMax - rgbMin);
    else if (rgbMax == rgb.g)
        hsv.h = 85 + 43 * (rgb.b - rgb.r) / (rgbMax - rgbMin);
    else
        hsv.h = 171 + 43 * (rgb.r - rgb.g) / (rgbMax - rgbMin);

    return hsv;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

GLSL Shader version based on Patapoms answer:

```
vec3 HSV2RGB( vec3 hsv )
{
    hsv.x = mod( 100.0 + hsv.x, 1.0 ); // Ensure [0,1[
    float   HueSlice = 6.0 * hsv.x; // In [0,6[
    float   HueSliceInteger = floor( HueSlice );
    float   HueSliceInterpolant = HueSlice - HueSliceInteger; // In [0,1[ for each hue slice
    vec3  TempRGB = vec3(   hsv.z * (1.0 - hsv.y), hsv.z * (1.0 - hsv.y * HueSliceInterpolant), hsv.z * (1.0 - hsv.y * (1.0 - HueSliceInterpolant)) );
    float   IsOddSlice = mod( HueSliceInteger, 2.0 ); // 0 if even (slices 0, 2, 4), 1 if odd (slices 1, 3, 5)
    float   ThreeSliceSelector = 0.5 * (HueSliceInteger - IsOddSlice); // (0, 1, 2) corresponding to slices (0, 2, 4) and (1, 3, 5)
    vec3  ScrollingRGBForEvenSlices = vec3( hsv.z, TempRGB.zx );           // (V, Temp Blue, Temp Red) for even slices (0, 2, 4)
    vec3  ScrollingRGBForOddSlices = vec3( TempRGB.y, hsv.z, TempRGB.x );  // (Temp Green, V, Temp Red) for odd slices (1, 3, 5)
    vec3  ScrollingRGB = mix( ScrollingRGBForEvenSlices, ScrollingRGBForOddSlices, IsOddSlice );
    float   IsNotFirstSlice = clamp( ThreeSliceSelector, 0.0,1.0 );                   // 1 if NOT the first slice (true for slices 1 and 2)
    float   IsNotSecondSlice = clamp( ThreeSliceSelector-1.0, 0.0,1. );              // 1 if NOT the first or second slice (true only for slice 2)
    return  mix( ScrollingRGB.xyz, mix( ScrollingRGB.zxy, ScrollingRGB.yzx, IsNotSecondSlice ), IsNotFirstSlice );    // Make the RGB rotate right depending on final slice index
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not C++ developer so I will not provide code. But I can provide simple **hsv2rgb**  algorithm (rgb2hsv [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Conversion_RGB_to_HSV_used_commonly_in_software_programming)) which I currently discover -  I update wiki with description: [HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#HSV_to_RGB_alternative) and [HLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#HSV_to_RGB_alternative). Main improvement is that I carefully observe r,g,b as hue functions and introduce simpler shape function to describe them (without loosing accuracy). **The Algorithm** - on input we have: h (0-255), s (0-255), v(0-255)

```
r = 255*f(5),   g = 255*f(3),   b = 255*f(1)
```

We use function f described as follows

```
f(n) = v/255 - (v/255)*(s/255)*max(min(k,4-k,1),0)
```

where (mod can return fraction part; k is floating point number)

```
k = (n+h*360/(255*60)) mod 6;
```

Here are snippets/PoV in SO in JS: [HSV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54024653/860099) and [HSL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54014428/860099)

Comment: Hello Kamil! I'm trying to use your algorithm and I have a question about that part `min(k,4-k,1)`. Why is there three values and what is exactly happening here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @EugeneAlexeev I fix article in wiki (someone broke it) - and update links here - so for deeper understanding read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#HSV_to_RGB_alternative)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an [online converter](https://www.tlbx.app/color-converter) with an article after explaining all the algorithms for color conversion.

You probably would prefer a ready-made C version but it should not be long to apply and it could help other people trying to do the same in another language or with another color space.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one which i just wrote this morning based on pretty much the same math as above:

```
/* math adapted from: http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-hsl.htm
 * reasonably optimized for speed, without going crazy */
void rgb_to_hsv (int r, int g, int b, float *r_h, float *r_s, float *r_v) {
  float rp, gp, bp, cmax, cmin, delta, l;
  int cmaxwhich, cminwhich;

  rp = ((float) r) / 255;
  gp = ((float) g) / 255;
  bp = ((float) b) / 255;

  //debug ("rgb=%d,%d,%d rgbprime=%f,%f,%f", r, g, b, rp, gp, bp);

  cmax = rp;
  cmaxwhich = 0; /* faster comparison afterwards */
  if (gp > cmax) { cmax = gp; cmaxwhich = 1; }
  if (bp > cmax) { cmax = bp; cmaxwhich = 2; }
  cmin = rp;
  cminwhich = 0;
  if (gp < cmin) { cmin = gp; cminwhich = 1; }
  if (bp < cmin) { cmin = bp; cminwhich = 2; }

  //debug ("cmin=%f,cmax=%f", cmin, cmax);
  delta = cmax - cmin;

  /* HUE */
  if (delta == 0) {
    *r_h = 0;
  } else {
    switch (cmaxwhich) {
      case 0: /* cmax == rp */
        *r_h = HUE_ANGLE * (fmod ((gp - bp) / delta, 6));
      break;

      case 1: /* cmax == gp */
        *r_h = HUE_ANGLE * (((bp - rp) / delta) + 2);
      break;

      case 2: /* cmax == bp */
        *r_h = HUE_ANGLE * (((rp - gp) / delta) + 4);
      break;
    }
    if (*r_h < 0)
      *r_h += 360;
  }

  /* LIGHTNESS/VALUE */
  //l = (cmax + cmin) / 2;
  *r_v = cmax;

  /* SATURATION */
  /*if (delta == 0) {
    *r_s = 0;
  } else {
    *r_s = delta / (1 - fabs (1 - (2 * (l - 1))));
  }*/
  if (cmax == 0) {
    *r_s = 0;
  } else {
    *r_s = delta / cmax;
  }
  //debug ("rgb=%d,%d,%d ---> hsv=%f,%f,%f", r, g, b, *r_h, *r_s, *r_v);
}


void hsv_to_rgb (float h, float s, float v, int *r_r, int *r_g, int *r_b) {
  if (h > 360)
    h -= 360;
  if (h < 0)
    h += 360;
  h = CLAMP (h, 0, 360);
  s = CLAMP (s, 0, 1);
  v = CLAMP (v, 0, 1);
  float c = v * s;
  float x = c * (1 - fabsf (fmod ((h / HUE_ANGLE), 2) - 1));
  float m = v - c;
  float rp, gp, bp;
  int a = h / 60;

  //debug ("h=%f, a=%d", h, a);

  switch (a) {
    case 0:
      rp = c;
      gp = x;
      bp = 0;
    break;

    case 1:
      rp = x;
      gp = c;
      bp = 0;
    break;

    case 2:
      rp = 0;
      gp = c;
      bp = x;
    break;

    case 3:
      rp = 0;
      gp = x;
      bp = c;
    break;

    case 4:
      rp = x;
      gp = 0;
      bp = c;
    break;

    default: // case 5:
      rp = c;
      gp = 0;
      bp = x;
    break;
  }

  *r_r = (rp + m) * 255;
  *r_g = (gp + m) * 255;
  *r_b = (bp + m) * 255;

  //debug ("hsv=%f,%f,%f, ---> rgb=%d,%d,%d", h, s, v, *r_r, *r_g, *r_b);
}
```

Comment: missing symbol definitions for CLAMP and HUE_ANGLE

Answer (score 0):

I created a possibly faster implementation by using 0-1 range for RGBS and V and 0-6 range for Hue (avoiding the division), and grouping the cases into two categories:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>

void fromRGBtoHSV(float rgb[], float hsv[])
{
//    for(int i=0; i<3; ++i)
//        rgb[i] = max(0.0f, min(1.0f, rgb[i]));

     hsv[0] = 0.0f;
     hsv[2] = max(rgb[0], max(rgb[1], rgb[2]));
     const float delta = hsv[2] - min(rgb[0], min(rgb[1], rgb[2]));

     if (delta < FLT_MIN)
         hsv[1] = 0.0f;
     else
     {
         hsv[1] = delta / hsv[2];
         if (rgb[0] >= hsv[2])
         {
             hsv[0] = (rgb[1] - rgb[2]) / delta;
             if (hsv[0] < 0.0f)
                 hsv[0] += 6.0f;
         }
         else if (rgb[1] >= hsv[2])
             hsv[0] = 2.0f + (rgb[2] - rgb[0]) / delta;
         else
             hsv[0] = 4.0f + (rgb[0] - rgb[1]) / delta;
     }    
}

void fromHSVtoRGB(const float hsv[], float rgb[])
{
    if(hsv[1] < FLT_MIN)
        rgb[0] = rgb[1] = rgb[2] = hsv[2];
    else
    {
        const float h = hsv[0];
        const int i = (int)h;
        const float f = h - i;
        const float p = hsv[2] * (1.0f - hsv[1]);

        if (i & 1) {
            const float q = hsv[2] * (1.0f - (hsv[1] * f));
            switch(i) {
            case 1:
                rgb[0] = q;
                rgb[1] = hsv[2];
                rgb[2] = p;
                break;
            case 3:
                rgb[0] = p;
                rgb[1] = q;
                rgb[2] = hsv[2];
                break;
            default:
                rgb[0] = hsv[2];
                rgb[1] = p;
                rgb[2] = q;
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            const float t = hsv[2] * (1.0f - (hsv[1] * (1.0f - f)));
            switch(i) {
            case 0:
                rgb[0] = hsv[2];
                rgb[1] = t;
                rgb[2] = p;
                break;
            case 2:
                rgb[0] = p;
                rgb[1] = hsv[2];
                rgb[2] = t;
                break;
            default:
                rgb[0] = t;
                rgb[1] = p;
                rgb[2] = hsv[2];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For 0-255 range just * 255.0f + 0.5f and assign it to an unsigned char (or divide by 255.0 to get the opposite).

Answer (score 0):

```
// This pair of functions convert HSL to RGB and vice-versa.
// It's pretty optimized for execution speed

typedef unsigned char       BYTE
typedef struct _RGB
{
    BYTE R;
    BYTE G;
    BYTE B;
} RGB, *pRGB;
typedef struct _HSL
{
    float   H;  // color Hue (0.0 to 360.0 degrees)
    float   S;  // color Saturation (0.0 to 1.0)
    float   L;  // Luminance (0.0 to 1.0)
    float   V;  // Value (0.0 to 1.0)
} HSL, *pHSL;

float   *fMin       (float *a, float *b)
{
    return *a <= *b?  a : b;
}

float   *fMax       (float *a, float *b)
{
    return *a >= *b? a : b;
}

void    RGBtoHSL    (pRGB rgb, pHSL hsl)
{
// See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV
// rgb->R, rgb->G, rgb->B: [0 to 255]
    float r =       (float) rgb->R / 255;
    float g =       (float) rgb->G / 255;
    float b =       (float) rgb->B / 255;
    float *min =    fMin(fMin(&r, &g), &b);
    float *max =    fMax(fMax(&r, &g), &b);
    float delta =   *max - *min;

// L, V [0.0 to 1.0]
    hsl->L = (*max + *min)/2;
    hsl->V = *max;
// Special case for H and S
    if (delta == 0)
    {
        hsl->H = 0.0f;
        hsl->S = 0.0f;
    }
    else
    {
// Special case for S
        if((*max == 0) || (*min == 1))
            hsl->S = 0;
        else
// S [0.0 to 1.0]
            hsl->S = (2 * *max - 2*hsl->L)/(1 - fabsf(2*hsl->L - 1));
// H [0.0 to 360.0]
        if      (max == &r)     hsl->H = fmod((g - b)/delta, 6);    // max is R
        else if (max == &g)     hsl->H = (b - r)/delta + 2;         // max is G
        else                    hsl->H = (r - g)/delta + 4;         // max is B
        hsl->H *= 60;
    }
}

void    HSLtoRGB    (pHSL hsl, pRGB rgb)
{
// See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV
    float a, k, fm1, fp1, f1, f2, *f3;
// L, V, S: [0.0 to 1.0]
// rgb->R, rgb->G, rgb->B: [0 to 255]
    fm1 = -1;
    fp1 = 1;
    f1 = 1-hsl->L;
    a = hsl->S * *fMin(&hsl->L, &f1);
    k = fmod(0 + hsl->H/30, 12);
    f1 = k - 3;
    f2 = 9 - k;
    f3 = fMin(fMin(&f1, &f2), &fp1) ;
    rgb->R = (BYTE) (255 * (hsl->L - a * *fMax(f3, &fm1)));

    k = fmod(8 + hsl->H/30, 12);
    f1 = k - 3;
    f2 = 9 - k;
    f3 = fMin(fMin(&f1, &f2), &fp1) ;
    rgb->G = (BYTE) (255 * (hsl->L - a * *fMax(f3, &fm1)));

    k = fmod(4 + hsl->H/30, 12);
    f1 = k - 3;
    f2 = 9 - k;
    f3 = fMin(fMin(&f1, &f2), &fp1) ;
    rgb->B = (BYTE) (255 * (hsl->L - a * *fMax(f3, &fm1)));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

[This link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSV_color_space) has formulas for what you want.  Then it's a matter of performance (numerical techniques) if you want it fast.