# Algorithm for "neon glow" graphics programming

Tags: algorithm, graphics

I am searching for an article or tutorial that explains how one can draw primitive shapes (mainly simple lines) with a (neon) glow effect on them in the graphical output of a computer program. I do not want to do some sophisticated stuff like for example in modern first pirson shooters or alike. I am more in a search for a simple solution, like the lines in that picture: http://tjl.co/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/NeonStripes.jpg -- but of course drawn by a computer program in my case.

The whole thing should run on a modern smart phone, so the hardware is a bit limited.

I do know a bit about OpenGL, but not too much, so unfortunately I am a bit lost here. Did some research on Google ("glow effect algoritm" and similar), but found either highly complex stuff for 3D games, or tutorials for Photoshop & co.

So what I would really need is an in-depth article on that subject, but not on a very advanced level. I hope thats even possible... I have just started with OpenGL, did some minor graphics programming in the past, but I am a long-year programmer now, so I would understand technical papers in general.

Does anyone of you know of such an article/paper/tutorial/anything?

Thanks in advance for all good advices!
Cheers!

Matthias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its jus a bunch of lines with different brightness/transperency. Basically, if you want a glow effect for 1px line, in a size of 20 pixels, then you draw 41 lines with width of 1 px. The middle line is with your base colour, other lines get colours that gradiently go from base color to 100% transperency (like in your example) or darkest colour variant (if you have black background, no transparency).
That is it. :)

Comment: ok, originally I thought that would be too easy -- but that approach works quite well :)

Answer (score 4):

This isn't something I've ever done, but looking at your example, the basic approach I'd use to try and recreate it would be...

1. Start with an algorithm for drawing a filled shape large enough to include the original shape and the glow. For example, a rectangle becomes a slightly larger rectangle, but with rounded corners. An infinitessimally-wide line becomes a thickened line with semi-circular caps. Subtract out the original shape (and fill the pixels for that normally).
2. For each pixel in the glow, the colour depends on the shortest distance to any part of the original shape. This normally reduces to the distance to the nearest point on a line (e.g. one edge of a rectangle).
3. The distance is translated to a colour value using probably Hue-Saturation-Value or a similar colour scheme, as well as reducing alpha (increasing transparency). For neon glows, you probably want constant hue, decreasing brightness, maybe increasing saturation, and decreasing alpha.
4. Translate the HSV/whatever colour value to RGB for output. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018313/algorithm-to-convert-rgb-to-hsv-and-hsv-to-rgb).

*EDIT* - I should probably have said HSL rather than HSV - in HSL, if L is at it's maximum value, the resulting colour is always white. For HSV, that's only true if saturation is also at zero. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV

The real trick is that even on a phone these days, I'd guess you probably should use hardware (shaders) for this - sorry, I don't know how that's done.

The "painters algorithm" overlaying of gradually smaller shapes that others have described here is also a possibility, but (1) possibly slower, depending on implementation issues, and (2) you may need to draw to an off-screen buffer, with some special handling for the alpha channel, then blit back to the screen to handle the transparency correctly - *if* you need transparency, that is.

**EDIT** - Silly me. An alternative approach is to apply a blur to your original shape (in greyscale), but instead of writing out the blurred pixels directly, apply the colour-transformation to each blurred pixel value.

A blur is basically a weighted moving average. Technically, a finite impulse response filter is implemented using a convolution, but the maths for that is a tad awkward and if you just want "a blur" of about the right size, draw a grayscale circle of pixels as your "weights" image.

The blur in this case basically replaces the distance-from-shape calculation.

Answer (score 2):

```
     _____________________
    |                     |
----|---------------------|-----> line
    |_____________________|
         gradient block
```

Break up your line into small non-overlapping blocks. Use whatever graphics primitive you have to draw a tilted rectangular gradient: the center is at 100% and the outer edge is at 0%.

Don't draw it on the image yet; you want to *blend* it with the image. Using regular transparency will just make it look like a random pipe or pole or something (unless you draw a white line, and your background is dark).

Here are two choices of blending mode:

- color dodge: `[blended pixel value] = (1-[overlay's pixel value]) / [bottom pixel value]`
- linear dodge: `[blended pixel value] = max([overlay's pixel value]+[bottom pixel value], 1)`

Then draw the line above the glow.

Comment: could you maybe explain the idea of a "tilted rectangular gradient" a bit?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to draw a curved "neon" line, simply draw it as a sequence of superimposed "neon dots" where each "neon dot" is a small circular image with transparency going from 0% at the origin to 100% at the edge of the circle.