# HSV (0 .. 255) to RGB (0 .. 255)

Tags: c++, algorithm, graphics, colors, color-picker

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Algorithm to convert RGB to HSV and HSV to RGB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018313/algorithm-to-convert-rgb-to-hsv-and-hsv-to-rgb)

Can someone explain on how to convert an HSV value to an RGB when the value is 0 to 255? Also,

For reference, I am trying to do this in C++.

Comment: Which part from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV - Converting to RGB you do not understand? Simply reposting here an algorithm would be without sense, please tell us which part is not working / you do not understand it

Comment: @ Ravadre, I was hoping for something in more "lamens terms". Wikipedia is notorious for presenting formulas in more complicated manner than necessary.

Comment: @ Kerrek SB, was being rude really necessary?

Comment: @ detunized, Actually, its not. Those are typically (0 ... 1) to (0 .. 255), etc

Comment: @judeclarke: so, scale it: if you have (0 ... 255), simply divide your values by 255 and then they will be in (0 ... 1), then you're good to go to use those algorithms!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it here
http://mjijackson.com/2008/02/rgb-to-hsl-and-rgb-to-hsv-color-model-conversion-algorithms-in-javascript

```
function hsvToRgb(h, s, v){
    var r, g, b;

    var i = Math.floor(h * 6);
    var f = h * 6 - i;
    var p = v * (1 - s);
    var q = v * (1 - f * s);
    var t = v * (1 - (1 - f) * s);

    switch(i % 6){
        case 0: r = v, g = t, b = p; break;
        case 1: r = q, g = v, b = p; break;
        case 2: r = p, g = v, b = t; break;
        case 3: r = p, g = q, b = v; break;
        case 4: r = t, g = p, b = v; break;
        case 5: r = v, g = p, b = q; break;
    }

    return [r * 255, g * 255, b * 255];
}
```

Edit:

I once wrote a color picker and used to understand all these. Back then, I looked at photoshop color picker, tried moving around the cross hair, observe the changes in hsv/rgb numbers and figured out how they work. In this case `i` seems to *locate* at which point the main color, hue, is pointed it. The value of hue is actually a degree of fully saturated colors in cycle which starts with red and ends with red. There's a triangle with each point representing R,G and B where 0 degree is R. Between R and G, it's Yellow, between R and B, it's Magenta and between B and G, it's cyan. There we have total 6 colors. Those 6 colors are from case 0 through 5.

Comment: I am sorry, I should have posted that I was hoping for HSV (0 .. 255) to RGB (0 .. 255) and a good explanation of it

Comment: The output is already in the range 0..255. You can convert the algorithm to have an input range to 0..255 by dividing h,s,v each by 255. But frankly, if you don't see that, you have a bigger problem

Comment: @ drhirsch, Being rude isn't helpful. I do not see how the input is (0 .. 255) as there is no explanation in the code. For example, why are the cases like that? What does each case do?

Comment: I you would have had a look at the mentioned wikipedia article, you would have recognized the six cases. And don't tell me I should explain this article in layman terms to you because you don't want to read it - I would consider this rude

Comment: @ drhirsch the wiki does not explain each case

Comment: @ Moe Sweet I hope to understand code when I use it

Comment: @ Moe Sweet, are the inputs of type 0 .. 1 or 0 .. 255?

Comment: The reason I ask because with h = 2, sat = 68 and v = 128, the values will be all negative, such as -8576.0 for p (b)

Comment: "Assumes h, s, and v are contained in the set [0, 1] and" It's written in the comments. Have you checked out the link yet?