# Is there support for the HSV color model in cairo / gdk / gtk?

Tags: gtk, cairo, gdk

Well, the question is quite simple I think. I would like to specify colors using the HSV color model (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV). However, all the cairo code seems to work exclusively with RGB / RGBA specifications. I could not find any ways to convert colors in gtk / gdk either. Am I missing something or is there some simple, portable way to convert colors (without additional libraries)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convertion HSV to RGB is just a couple of lines of code, [see for example here (no code)](http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/hsv-to-rgb.htm) or this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018313/algorithm-to-convert-rgb-to-hsv-and-hsv-to-rgb-in-range-0-255-for-both).

---

But to answer your original question:

AFAIK `cairo` is entirly based on RGBA model, see [`cairo_format_t` in manual](http://cairographics.org/manual/cairo-Image-Surfaces.html#cairo-format-t).

Comment: Well, I would have appreciated it if the functionality were in cairo/gdk/gtk. But pasting SO code is probably ok too...