# How to show the name of a color?

Tags: eclipse, opencv, image-processing, android

I'm working on OpenCV4Android "BlobColorDetection". 
I try to know the HSV color from this object and display it with a `Toast`.

How can I make a condition that when `Value = 160 - 180` then it shows a message `Color = Blue`?

```
mBlobColorHsv = Core.sumElems(touchedRegionHsv);
int pointCount = touchedRect.width*touchedRect.height;
for (int i = 0; i < mBlobColorHsv.val.length; i++) {
    mBlobColorHsv.val[i] /= pointCount;
    mBlobColorRgba = converScalarHsv2Rgba(mBlobColorHsv);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Value = " + mBlobColorHsv, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

[image]

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35482205/5008845) should help

Comment: Look also to this [RGB value base color name](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37476754/2521214)

Comment: How to implentation on Java Android ? still confused @Miki