# opencv create mat and add elements

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

There is a jpg file, I would like to rearrange it into a Mat of n*3, 3 columns for BGR, n rows for number of pixels in the jpg image.

Here is what I did so far.

```
    Mat img = imread(test.jpg);
    Mat imgHSV;
    cvtColor(img, imgHSV, COLOR_BGR2HSV);
    vector<Mat> imgHSV_split;
    split(imgHSV,imgHSV_split);   //split the 3 channel image into 3 single channel mats

Mat img_combind_feature(imgHSV.rows*imgHSV.cols(),3,CV_8UC1);
for(int i=0; i < imgHSV.row; i++){
for(int j=0; j < imgHSV.col; j++){


for (int k=0; k<3; k++){


img_combind_feature.row(l).col(k) = imgHSV_split[k].row(i).col(j);

}
}
}
```

Before I run this code, I tried a simple 3*3 version,

```
    Mat img = imread(test.jpg);
    Mat imgHSV;
    cvtColor(img, imgHSV, COLOR_BGR2HSV);
    vector<Mat> imgHSV_split;
    split(imgHSV,imgHSV_split);   //split the 3 channel image into 3 single channel mats

Mat img_combind_feature(1,3,CV_8UI1);   
img_combind_feature.row(0).col(0) = imgHSV_split[0].row(0).col(0);

img_combind_feature.row(0).col(1) = imgHSV_split[1].row(0).col(0);

img_combind_feature.row(0).col(2) = imgHSV_split[2].row(0).col(0);


cout << imgHSV_split[0].row(0).col(0) << endl;
cout << img_combind_feature.row(0).col(0) << endl;
```

The two outputs are different.

`[ 43]
[232]`
 
Is this due to some data type translation between the two Mats?
And, I am not sure this is a good way to do it, if there are any more manageable ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overcomplicating this.

To turn a 3 channel image `rows x cols` to a `n x 3`, with `n = rows * cols`, you can simply use [reshape](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-reshape) like:

```
Mat img = ... // 3 channels

int n = img.rows * img.cols;
Mat data = img.reshape(1, n); // 1 channel, n rows, the # of cols will be automaticallt set to 3.
```

`data` will be the `n x 3` you are looking for.

---

Most likely, you need to use `data` with `kmeans`, which needs a `CV_32F` input matrix. Then you can convert `data` to `CV_32F` like:

```
data.convertTo(data, CV_32F);
```

You can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34734939/5008845) for an example with `kmeans`, that will show also how to restore the result into the original shape.

Comment: That is exactly what I need it for, kmeans! Thank you!

Comment: I did click on the tick, and it is green, is it accepted