# Kmeans Assertion error: my Mat isn't empty though

Tags: c++, opencv

My `kmeans()` function is failing with the error:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (N >= K) in cv::kmeans, file C:\builds\master_Pac
>   kSlave-win32-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\core\src\kmeans.cpp, line 231

Whats my error? 'N >= K' must mean its checking whether the Mat rows*cols(length) is > clusters - which mine is (I think). My Mat has 1 row with around 80k columns. Is my `Mat` that I am passing as the first parameter (for kmeans) empty of pixel/voxel data? I have confirmed that this parameter is a 'collapsed' image (1 row, 80K columns). So its not quite empty but it could all that it's all black pixels which may be the error?

```
Mat image = imread("images/jp.png", CV_32F); // The Jurassic Park movie logo
cvtColor(image, image, CV_BGR2RGB);

Mat collapsedImage = image.reshape(1, 1);
collapsedImage.convertTo(collapsedImage, CV_32F);

int clusterCount = 2;
Mat labels, centres;

// Assertion error thrown here
kmeans(collapsedImage, clusterCount, labels,
    TermCriteria(TermCriteria::EPS + TermCriteria::COUNT, 10, 1.0),
    3, KMEANS_PP_CENTERS, centres);

imshow("flat", collapsedImage); // shows long flat with all black pixels
imshow("image", image);
```

Comment: In `Mat image = imread("images/jp.png", CV_32F);` the `CV_32F` doesn't make sense.... If you want to load a BGR image (3 channels), you can use `Mat image = imread(path);` as default, or `Mat image = imread(path, IMREAD_COLOR);`

Comment: You can also check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34734939/5008845) how to use kmeans with color images.

Answer (score 0):

Ok looks like the problem was my reshaping. It should be:

```
Mat collapsedImage = image.reshape(1, image.rows * image.cols);
```