# Arduino RGB LED Control from 2 pots

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to write some code that reads a voltage from 2 different pots and converts that to 3 pwm outputs that I can then send to an RGB LED. My idea is to use something like a colour map that is used to plot complex functions, but I'm not sure how to implement that. Any suggestions?

```
#define COLOUR_POT_INPUT 4
#define INTENSITY_POT_INPUT 3
#define LED_RED 9
#define LED_GREEN 10
#define LED_BLUE 11

float colour_angle;
float colour_radius;
float colour_x_value;
float colour_y_value;

int red_value;
int green_value;
int blue_value;

const float pi = 3.1415;

void setup() {
  pinMode(COLOUR_POT_INPUT, INPUT);
  pinMode(INTENSITY_POT_INPUT, INPUT);
  pinMode(LED_RED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED_GREEN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED_BLUE, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  colour_angle = analogRead(COLOUR_POT_INPUT);
  colour_radius = analogRead(INTENSITY_POT_INPUT);

  colour_angle = map(colour_angle, 0, 1023, 0, 2*pi);
  colour_radius = map(colour_radius, 0, 1023, 0, 255);

  colour_x_value = colour_radius*cos(colour_angle);
  colour_y_value = colour_radius*sin(colour_angle);

}

//Insert function here that maps colour x and y value to red green blue 
value
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `colour_angle` and `colour_radius` represent hue and saturation respectively, then you can use any HSL/HSV-to-RGB conversion code, with a fixed lightness/value.

Picking randomly from google results:

[HSL to RGB conversion](http://dystopiancode.blogspot.com/2012/06/hsl-rgb-conversion-algorithms-in-c.html)

[HSV to RGB conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018313/algorithm-to-convert-rgb-to-hsv-and-hsv-to-rgb-in-range-0-255-for-both)