# How to use setPixel with HSV instead of RGB?

Tags: c#, colors, hsb

```
Bitmap bmap = new Bitmap(B2);

int width = bmap.Width;
int height = bmap.Height;

for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        Color c = bmap.GetPixel(x, y);
        float h, s, b;
        h = c.GetHue();
        s = c.GetSaturation();
        b = c.GetBrightness();
    }
}
```

I wanted to filter out all the shades of yellow and then change it all to white. Then I have use HSB which makes it easier. Do I have to convert them back to RGB in order to use `setPixel`?

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove the yellow color in the whole photo? It would be great if you could attach the photo.

Comment: Yes, bitmaps are in RGB, See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018313/algorithm-to-convert-rgb-to-hsv-and-hsv-to-rgb-in-range-0-255-for-both) for conversion code. While it is in C, it should be trivial to port to C#

Comment: Or [this question for HSL <-> RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353211/hsl-to-rgb-color-conversion)

Comment: yes, i wanted to remove all the yellow color in the photo and change it to white.

Comment: tq for your answer